# How to write Unicode output to .csv to be used in Excel?

Tags: r, excel, unicode, utf-8

I have a data set containing Chinese characters that I worked on using UTF-8 is processed. Part of the data looks like this:

```
encod   cKeyword
UTF-8   <U+5169><U+7528> <U+5305> 27 bloide herme
UTF-8   <U+593E> <U+62C9><U+934A> <U+9577> loewe
UTF-8   <U+5169><U+7528> <U+5305> <U+8FF7><U+4F60> 31 lim pashli phillip
UTF-8   <U+5305> <U+624B><U+62FF> givenchy pandora
```

When I use `write.csv(data, "file.csv", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")` , I get a .csv file that when opened displays the exact same thing in Excel. But I need the Unicode to be displayed as its Chinese character.

How can I get it to write Chinese characters instead?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly telling Excel to import unicode, q.v. [here](http://help.tune.com/marketing-console/how-to-import-a-unicode-csv-to-excel/) ?

Comment: No knowledge about `R` but those `<U+5169>` are looking strange. How shall those be converted to unicode? And from what software shall that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your characters are represented with [unicode code points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596576/simplified-chinese-unicode-table).

```
Python 2.7.10
>>> s = '\u5169' # <U+5169> represented in unicode
>>> print s.decode('unicode_escape')
兩
```

In Excel, the following function will convert your code point into character representation:

```
=UNICHAR(HEX2DEC(5169))
```

Or, here is a more end-to-end example. The following Python 2.7 code with `unicodecsv` (`pip install unicodecsv`) module, will convert your R (`r.csv`) output into Excel input (`excel.csv`):

```
import unicodecsv as csv, re

csvwrite = open('excel.csv', 'wb')
w = csv.writer(csvwrite, encoding='utf-8')

with open('r.csv', 'rb') as csvread:
    rows = csv.reader(csvread, delimiter='\t')
    for row in rows:
        p = re.compile('\<U\+([0-9a-fA-F]+)\>')
        iterator = p.finditer(row[1])
        for match in iterator:            
            s = '%s%s' % ('\u', match.group().replace('U+', '').replace('<', '').replace('>', ''))            
            row[1] = row[1].replace(match.group(), s.decode('unicode_escape'))
        w.writerow(row)
```

Take the generated `excel.csv` and import into Excel (not just open), but following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6488070/1559300) post.

I don't have R installed, but it may also be possible for it to write output in the format Excel understands, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675360/utf-8-file-output-in-r) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267099/r-write-csv-with-utf-16-encoding).

Hope this helps..

-- ab1

Comment: Thanks! This helped tons. Together with the advise from TimBiegeleisen, I managed to achieve what I needed