# Hebrew Encoding Hell in R and writing a UTF-8 table in Windows

Tags: r, text, encoding, hebrew

I'm trying to save data extracted with `RSelenium` from https://www.magna.isa.gov.il/Details.aspx?l=he, but although R succeeds printing Hebrew character to the console, it does not when exporting TXT, CSV or in other simple R functions, like `data.frame()`, `readHTMLTable()`, etc.

Here goes an example.

```
> head(lines)
[1] "גלובל פיננס ג'י.אר. 2 בע\"מ נתונים כספיים באלפי דולר ארה\"ב"
[2] "513435404"                                                  
[3] ""                                                           
[4] ""                                                           
[5] ""                                                           
[6] "4,481"
```

First line changes to weird characters (below) when using `data.frame()`

```
> head(as.data.frame(lines))
[1] <U+05D2><U+05DC><U+05D5><U+05D1><U+05DC> <U+05E4><U+05D9><U+05E0><U+05E0><U+05E1> <U+05D2>'<U+05D9>.<U+05D0><U+05E8>. 2 <U+05D1><U+05E2>"<U+05DE> <U+05E0><U+05EA><U+05D5><U+05E0><U+05D9><U+05DD> <U+05DB><U+05E1><U+05E4><U+05D9><U+05D9><U+05DD> <U+05D1><U+05D0><U+05DC><U+05E4><U+05D9> <U+05D3><U+05D5><U+05DC><U+05E8> <U+05D0><U+05E8><U+05D4>"<U+05D1>
```

The same happens when exporting .TXT or .CSV by `write.table` or `write.csv`:

```
write.csv(lines,"lines.csv",row.names=FALSE)
```

[image]

I tried to change the encoding to "UTF-8", like suggested in several alike questions, yet, the issue remains in a different format:

```
iconv(lines, to = "UTF-8")
1 ׳’׳׳•׳‘׳ ׳₪׳™׳ ׳ ׳¡ ׳’'׳™.׳׳¨. 2 ׳‘׳¢"׳ ׳ ׳×׳•׳ ׳™׳ ׳›׳¡׳₪׳™׳™׳ ׳‘׳׳׳₪׳™ ׳“׳•׳׳¨ ׳׳¨׳”"׳‘
```

Same for Hebrew ISO-8859-8:

```
iconv(lines, to = "ISO-8859-8")
    1 ×'×o×.×'×o ×₪×T× × ×! ×''×T.××¨. 2 ×'×¢"×z × ×a×.× ×T× ×>×!×₪×T×T× ×'××o×₪×T ×"×.×o×¨ ××¨×""×'
```

I don't understand why the console prints Hebrew characters well while `write.table()`, `write.csv()` and `data.frame()` presents encoding issues.

Anyone to help me exporting it?

> > That was answered by Ken, exporting text with writeLines() worked well:

```
f = file("lines.txt", open = "wt", encoding = "UTF-8")
writeLines(lines, "lines.txt", useBytes = TRUE)
close(f)
```

Yet, **the main issue** R has with Hebrew encoding **is** while **dealing with tables**, in the form of **as.data.frame()**, **write.table(**) and **write.csv()**. Any thoughts?

Some machine info:

```
Sys.info()
                 sysname                      release                      version 
               "Windows"                      "7 x64" "build 7601, Service Pack 1" 
                nodename                      machine                        login 
              "TALIS-TP"                        "x86"

> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"
```

Comment: try using write.csv(lines,"lines.csv",enconding ="UTF-8')

Comment: It's no doubt to do with the encoding from your `readLines()` statement. Please include a few lines of the input file, and the command you used to read it. Also you want to make sure that `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the `data.frame()` command.

Comment: Are you sure your input file is encoded as UTF-8? (and not for instance Windows-1255)

Comment: Hi Diego, I tried, but i did not work.

Comment: Hi ken, I am reading the file from the web, using RSelenium and the command webElem = remDrv$findElements("class", "rGridNumberDir"), then a loop to get getElementAttribute("outerHTML").

Comment: Hi ken, not sure the original encoding since the file is presented in HTML table in the website.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Many many people have similar problems working with UTF-8 text on platforms that have 8-bit system encodings (Windows).  Encoding in R can be tricky, because different methods handle encoding and conversions differently, and what appears to work fine on one platform (OS X or Linux) works poorly on another.

The problem has to do with your output connection and how Windows handles encodings and text connections.  I've tried to replicate the problem using some Hebrew texts in both UTF-8 and an 8-bit encoding.  We'll walk through the file reading issues as well, since there could be some snags there too.

#### For Tests

- Created a short Hebrew language text file, encoded as UTF-8: [hebrew-utf8.txt](http://kenbenoit.net/files/hebrew-utf8.txt)
- Created a short Hebrew language text file, encoded as ISO-8859-8: [hebrew-iso-8859-8.txt](http://kenbenoit.net/files/hebrew-iso-8859-8.txt).  (Note: You might need to tell your browser about the encoding in order to view this one properly - that's the case for Safari for instance.)

#### Ways to read the files

Now let's experiment.  I am using Windows 7 for these tests (it actually works in OS X, my usual OS).

```
lines <- readLines("http://kenbenoit.net/files/hebrew-utf8.txt")
lines
## [1] "×”×¢×‘×¨×™ ×”×•× ×—×‘×¨ ×‘×§×‘×•×¦×” ×”×›× ×¢× ×™×ª ×©×œ ×©×¤×•×ª ×©×ž×™×•×ª."                                                                     
## [2] "×–×• ×”×™×ª×” ×©×¤×ª× ×©×œ ×”×™×”×•×“×™× ×ž×•×§×“×, ××‘×œ ×ž×Ÿ 586 ×œ×¤× ×”\"×¡ ×–×” ×”×ª×—×™×œ ×œ×”×™×•×ª ×ž×•×—×œ×£ ×¢×œ ×™×“×™ ×‘××¨×ž×™×ª."
```

That failed because it assumed the encoding was your system encoding, Windows-1252.  But because no conversion occurred when you read the files, you can fix this just by setting the Encoding bit to UTF-8:

```
# this sets the bit for UTF-8
Encoding(lines) <- "UTF-8"
lines
## [1] "העברי הוא חבר בקבוצה הכנענית של שפות שמיות."                                          
## [2] "זו היתה שפתם של היהודים מוקדם, אבל מן 586 לפנה\"ס זה התחיל להיות מוחלף על ידי בארמית."
```

But better to do this when you read the file:

```
# this does it in one pass
lines2 <- readLines("http://kenbenoit.net/files/hebrew-utf8.txt", encoding = "UTF-8")
lines2[1]
## [1] "העברי הוא חבר בקבוצה הכנענית של שפות שמיות."
Encoding(lines2)
## [1] "UTF-8" "UTF-8"
```

Now look at what happens if we try to read the same text, but encoded as the 8-bit ISO Hebrew code page.

```
lines3 <- readLines("http://kenbenoit.net/files/hebrew-iso-8859-8.txt")
lines3[1]
## [1] "äòáøé äåà çáø á÷áåöä äëðòðéú ùì ùôåú ùîéåú."
```

Setting the Encoding bit is of no help here, because what was read does not map to the Unicode code points for Hebrew, and `Encoding()` does no actual encoding conversion, it merely sets an extra bit that can be used to tell R one of a few possible encoding values.  We could have solved this by adding `encoding = "ISO-8859-8"` to the `readLines()` call.  We can also convert the text after loading, using `iconv()`:

```
# this will not fix things
Encoding(lines3) <- "UTF-8"
lines3[1]
## [1] "\xe4\xf2\xe1\xf8\xe9 \xe4\xe5\xe0 \xe7\xe1\xf8 \xe1\xf7\xe1\xe5\xf6\xe4 \xe4\xeb\xf0\xf2\xf0\xe9\xfa \xf9\xec \xf9\xf4\xe5\xfa \xf9\xee\xe9\xe5\xfa."
# but this will
iconv(lines3, "ISO-8859-8", "UTF-8")[1]
## [1] "העברי הוא חבר בקבוצה הכנענית של שפות שמיות."
```

Overall I think the method used above for `lines2` is the best approach.

#### How to output the files, preserving encoding

Now to your question about how to write this:  The safest way is to control your connection at a low level, where you can specify the encoding.  Otherwise, the default is for R/Windows to choose your system encoding, which will lose the UTF-8.  I thought this would work, which does work **absolutely fine in OS X** - and on OS X also works fine calling `writeLines()` just naming a text file without the textConnection.

```
## to write lines, use the encoding option of a connection object
f <- file("hebrew-output-UTF-8.txt", open = "wt", encoding = "UTF-8")
writeLines(lines2, f)
close(f)
```

But it does not work on Windows.  You can see the Windows 7 results here: [hebrew-output-UTF-8-file_encoding.txt](http://kenbenoit.net/files/hebrew-output-UTF-8-file_encoding.txt).

So, here is how to do it **in Windows**: Once you are sure your text is encoded as UTF-8, just write it as raw bytes, without using any encoding, like this:

```
writeLines(lines2, "hebrew-output-UTF-8-useBytesTRUE.txt", useBytes = TRUE)
```

You can see the results at [hebrew-output-UTF-8-useBytesTRUE.txt](http://kenbenoit.net/files/hebrew-output-UTF-8-useBytesTRUE.txt), which is now UTF-8 and looks correct.

> Added for write.csv

Note that the only reason you would want to do this is to make the .csv file available for import into other software, such as Excel. (And good luck working with UTF-8 in Excel/Windows...)  Otherwise, you should just write the data.table as binary using `write(myDataFrame, file = "myDataFrame.RData")`.  But if you really need to output .csv, then:

#### How to write UTF-8 .csv files from a `data.table` in Windows

The problem with writing UTF-8 files using `write.table()` and `write.csv()` is that these open text connections, and Windows has limitations about encodings and text connections with respect to UTF-8.  ([This post](https://tomizonor.wordpress.com/2013/04/17/file-utf8-windows/) offers a helpful explanation.)  Following from an SO answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267099/r-write-csv-with-utf-16-encoding), we can override this to write our own function to output UTF-8 .csv files.

This assumes that you have already set the `Encoding()` for any character elements to `"UTF-8"` (which happens upon import above for `lines2`).

```
df <- data.frame(int = 1:2, text = lines2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

write_utf8_csv <- function(df, file) {
    firstline <- paste('"', names(df), '"', sep = "", collapse = " , ")
    data <- apply(df, 1, function(x) {paste('"', x, '"', sep = "", collapse = " , ")})
    writeLines(c(firstline, data), file , useBytes = TRUE)
}

write_utf8_csv(df, "df_csv.txt")
```

When we now look at that file in non-Unicode-challenged OS, it now looks fine:

```
KBsMBP15-2:Desktop kbenoit$ cat df_csv.txt 
"int" , "text"
"1" , "העברי הוא חבר בקבוצה הכנענית של שפות שמיות."
"2" , "זו היתה שפתם של היהודים מוקדם, אבל מן 586 לפנה"ס זה התחיל להיות מוחלף על ידי בארמית."
KBsMBP15-2:Desktop kbenoit$ file df_csv.txt 
df_csv.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Comment: Does this method fix the problem of printing Hebrew data.frames or data.tables in R-Studio or is just dedicated to write.table? I have answered a question about [printing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35973507/reading-a-utf-8-text-file-in-hebrew-shows-gibrish-in-rstudios-console-and-fin/38730975#38730975) in Hebrew and the problem seems to be in the use of `format` on non-English characters within R-studio.